# Linux nohup process terminated when using tailf

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

Here is my script (`run.sh`):

```
rm -f nohup.out
nohup myproc &
tailf nohup.out
```

If I run the script (`sh run.sh`) then press <kbd>Control-C</kbd>, `myproc` will be terminated,
but if I comment the `tailf nohup.out` part, `myproc` will run on background as expected. 
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Ctrl-C doesn't probably terminate `myproc`, it terminates `tail` which leads you into thinking that `myproc` has been terminated.

Comment: No, it really terminates `myproc`. I used 'ps -ef|grep myproc' and can not find the process's id.

Comment: @honeytidy my guess would be, there is no myproc because of it has finished

Comment: @cur4so, Nope! myproc is a long time runing process (about 1 days for running).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `SIGHUP` (which `nohup` would catch) but `SIGINT` which you send by pressing <kbd>Control-C</kbd>. This is propagated to your process.

See this [blog post](http://dhauweele.blogspot.de/2013/10/getting-rid-of-sigint.html) for more details.

From what I read from that post you could change your code to something like this:

```
setsid myproc 1> output.log 2>&1  &
tail -f output.log
```

If you dont want to use your own output redirection, you can still use `nohup`:

```
setsid nohup ping -c 30 localhost &
tail -f nohup.out
```

Hope this helps!